# Cursors with LOOP

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, cursor

Sorry for the huge code. All I am trying to do is increment the variable `YM1` (201702, 201703, 201704) by one month, execute the SQL statement and display the result using CURSOR.

CURRENT BEHAVIOR: The `YM1` variable is not incremented. The code executes but always uses `YM1 = '201702'`.

```
YEAR_MONTH 201701 201702 0
YEAR_MONTH 201701 201703 0
YEAR_MONTH 201701 201704 0
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
YEAR_MONTH 201701 201702 0
YEAR_MONTH 201701 201703 10
YEAR_MONTH 201701 201704 20
```

Please let me know what I am missing. Breaking my head. Thanks a lot for the time.

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
    YM   VARCHAR2(10) := '201701';
    YM1  VARCHAR2(10) := '201702';
    row1 number := 0;

    CURSOR counts is
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   **table1 a**
        WHERE  a.year_month = YM
        AND    EXISTS
               ( SELECT 'Y'
                 FROM   **table2 b** 
                 WHERE  a.id = b.id
                 AND    b.year_month = YM1 );
BEGIN
    OPEN counts;
    LOOP
        FETCH counts INTO row1;
        dbms_output.put_line('YEAR_MONTH '||YM||' '||YM1||' '||row1);
        YM1 := TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(YM1,'YYYY-MM'), +1), 'YYYYMM');
        EXIT WHEN YM1 > '201704'
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE counts;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when you open the cursor it selects all the records that match the `YM1` variable *at the time of opening*. So your loop will fetch one row which  exhausts the cursor. The next fetch fetches nothing and so the value of `row1` is not updated.

To pick up fresh values you need to open and close the cursor each time:

```
DECLARE
  YM VARCHAR2(10) := '201701'
  YM1 VARCHAR2(10) := '201702'
  row1 number := 0;
  CURSOR counts is
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM table1 a
     WHERE a.YEAR_MONTH = YM
     AND EXISTS (SELECT 'Y'
                 FROM table2 b 
                 WHERE a.id = b.id
                 AND b.YEAR_MONTH  = YM1);
BEGIN
  LOOP
    OPEN counts;
    FETCH counts INTO row1;
    dbms_output.put_line('YEAR_MONTH '||YM||' '||YM1||' '||row1);
    YM1 := TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(YM1,'YYYY-MM'), +1), 'YYYYMM');
    EXIT WHEN YM1 > '201704'
    CLOSE counts;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no increment happening as part  of the loop so it is always the same.
I am not sure if you are assuming this as the logic to increment YM1 value but it will never do that.
    ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(YM1,'YYYY-MM'), +1)

And are you trying to increment YM? Try increment with the below statement for YM1
YM1 := TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(YM1,'YYYY-MM'), +1), 'YYYYMM');

Editing to provide you the output..

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
YM VARCHAR2(10) := '201701';
YM1 VARCHAR2(10) := '201702';
BEGIN
 dbms_output.put_line('           Timing        YM       YM1');
 dbms_output.put_line('Before Increment'||YM||' '||YM1);
 LOOP
   YM1 := TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(YM1,'YYYY-MM'), +1), 'YYYYMM');
   dbms_output.put_line('After Increment '||YM||' '||YM1);
   EXIT WHEN YM1 > '201704';
 END LOOP;
END;
/

Timing        YM       YM1
Before Increment201701 201702
After Increment 201701 201703
After Increment 201701 201704
After Increment 201701 201705


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I just executed removing the tables and cursor..

Comment: I am trying to increment YM1. It is a typo in the code I pasted above, I had used YM1 := TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(YM1,'YYYY-MM'), +1), 'YYYYMM'); Please see **CURRENT RESULT**, YM is the same(201701) but YM1 increments only in the result(201702,201703,201704). Hope this is clear.

Comment: I just gave you the output from my execution, it is incrementing.. check once

Comment: I am trying to increment YM1 and use it in the CURSOR block inside the EXISTS clause. Your code is missing CURSOR, which is what I want to implement. Thanks fir sharing this.